# Insert Pair as a key in map using c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

I want to know how can insert pair in map using c++, here's my code:

```
map< pair<int, string>, int> timeline;
```

I tried to insert it using:

```
timeline.insert(pair<pair<int, string> , int>(make_pair(12, "str"), 33);
//and
timeline.insert(make_pair(12, "str"), 33);
```

but I got error

`\main.cpp|66|error: no matching function for call to 'std::map<std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char> >, int&>::insert(std::pair<int, const char*>, int)'|`

Comment: you should post the (full) error message

Comment: @appleapple i added it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) expects `std::map::value_type` as its argument, i.e. `std::pair<const std::pair<int, string>, int>`. e.g.

```
timeline.insert(make_pair(make_pair(12, "str"), 33));
```

or simpler as

```
timeline.insert({{12, "str"}, 33});
```

If you want to construct element in-place you can also use [`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace), e.g.

```
timeline.emplace(make_pair(12, "str"), 33);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gyN57fyK8vmKToXQ)

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, simplify.

```
auto key = std::make_pair(12, "str");
auto value = 33;

timeline.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the traditional way:

```
timeline[key] = value;
```

For instertion and retrival of pair:

```
 timeline[{1,"stackOverFlow"}] = 69;
   
   for(auto i: timeline)
        {
            
            cout<< i.first.first;
            cout<< i.first.second;
            cout<< i.second;
        }
```